# Is it possible to get reference of Session Object (Datastax driver) from TransactionService

Tags: scalardb

My code uses `Session` Object from Datastax Java driver. Is it possible to get reference of the underlying Session object from TransactionService? As I am experimenting with ScalarDB at the moment, I want to avoid changing the code at many places. I'll prefer to pass the Session Object and also the TransactionService object to the classes I am changing for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't.
And it won't be since it breaks the abstraction and OO principle.
(TransactionService doesn't even know it uses the java driver underneath)